# Volumetric fire looks cuboid

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, fire

[image]

I do not know why. The tutorial I followed was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_ybn4tYxs4.

I am not able to get the result of a nicely shaped flame.

Below is my set up for the domain:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have brightness set to 1 on both of your bright contrast nodes, it should be 0 as you don't want to modify the brightness at all, increasing the brightness like this is effectively setting the background density to a value above zero, so the whole cube is being rendered.

In fact you don't even need those nodes at all

The other thing I noticed is the top attribute node should use the *density* attribute for the smoke, rather than the *flame* attribute.

In order for volumetric materials to render correctly you will also need to go to the light paths section of the render settings and set the number of volume bounces to something reasonable.

Comment: henlow, I have tried this again with the bright contrast nodes removed, but my flames died. 

https://imgur.com/a/RtLLA18

I am not sure what to do anymore

Comment: @lala Try plugging in just the emission shader to the volume output and see what you get

Comment: Still dead flame. Would you like me to send my file for you to inspect?
[link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx23p.png]

Comment: @lala sure, that would make it easier.

Comment: here ya go https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RE7-TEOMjem_NcHoK-v1uv3GOfHXailr

Comment: @lala, other than volumetric bounces, I can't see anything wrong. You simulation isn't baked so it was empty when I opened the file. You may want to bake it or replay the animation from the start of the timeline and check in solid shaded mode to make sure that the fire simulation has actually been generated. Moving the simulation objects to a different layer and just showing that can also help with just rendering what you are trying to get working (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html)

Comment: holy mama, i clicked bake an it works. but why?

Comment: @lala blender doesn't save the results of simulations by default, baking is how you do it. Baking essentially saves and freezes the result of the simulation so blender won't need to, or try to, recalculate it. Also feel free to click the tick next to the answer to show that it was the solution to your problem.